# replace last occurrence if equal the first

Tags: python, pandas

I have df like:

```
  value
0 yes
1 nan
2 no
3 nan
4 yes
5 no
6 yes
7 nan
8 nan
9 nan
```

I do not have a guarantee that the first not `nan` value,`yes`, will be at the first row. It could as well start at later index.

I need to check if the first occurrence of `string` **that is not** `Nan`, equals the last string that is not `nan`, and if so, set it to `nan`.

Here, index 6 equals index 0, means we need to set it to nan and result in :

```
  value
0 yes
1 nan
2 no
3 nan
4 yes
5 no
6 nan  #set to nan since equals first non Nan value
7 nan
8 nan
9 nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) and
[`Series.last_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html) for indices first and last non missing values, get values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), last use `if-else` statement for set values by scalars:

```
first_idx = df['value'].first_valid_index()
last_idx = df['value'].last_valid_index()
first = df.loc[first_idx, 'value']
last = df.loc[first_idx, 'value']

df.loc[last_idx, 'value'] = np.nan if first == last else last
```

Or assign only if True :

```
if first == last:
    df.loc[last_idx, 'value'] = np.nan
```

---

```
print (df)
  value
0   yes
1   NaN
2    no
3   NaN
4   yes
5    no
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
```

If only one non missing value (and avoid replacement) also test if not equal indices:

```
print (df)
  value
0   yes
1   NaN
2   NaN


first_idx = df['value'].first_valid_index()
last_idx = df['value'].last_valid_index()
first = df.loc[first_idx, 'value']
last = df.loc[first_idx, 'value']

df.loc[last_idx, 'value'] = np.nan if (first == last) and (first_idx != last_idx) else last
print (df)
  value
0   yes
1   NaN
2   NaN
```